# How to prevent repeated same data on php & ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have build a search filter with dropdown for filtering data with selecting dropdown. But it is showing the same result data repeatedly and does not show data correctly with matching query. Please check the demo http://speedymarket.byethost5.com/test_filter/atest.php

atest.php

```
<?php
    include_once 'dbcon.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title></title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

         <?php
    $res = $MySQLiconn->query("SELECT title FROM store order by title");
    $count = $res->num_rows;
 ?>

           Title:   <select  name="title" id="title">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
                <?php

                    if($count > 0)
    {
        while($row=$res->fetch_array())
        {
                ?>

                <option  value="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['title']; ?> </option>
                <?php        }} ?>
                </select>

            <select  name="date" id="datee">

                <option value="cdate"> Current Date </option>
                <option value="pdate"> Past Deals </option>

                </select>
        <div id="title-data"></div>
      <div id="title-data2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

title.php

```
<?php
 $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","filterdatabase");
 if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . $con->connect_error);
 }
 if(isset($_POST['title']))
 {
  $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
  $arrChartData[] = array();
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM store
 WHERE title LIKE '%".$title."%' group by storeid";
 $res = $con->query($sql) or trigger_error($con->error."[$sql]");
 while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
 {
     $arrChartData[] = $row;
 echo $row['title'] . " " . $row['startdate'];
 echo "<br />";
 }
 }
 if(isset($_POST['date']) )
 {
     //$title =(isset(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])) ? $_POST['title'] : null);
     $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
     $date= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date']);
     if($date=="cdate")
         {
              $arrChartData[] = array();
                 $sql="select DISTINCT  * from 
             store where  startdate > CURRENT_DATE() and title LIKE '%".$title."%' group by storeid";


             $res = $con->query($sql) or trigger_error($con->error."[$sql]");
             while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
                 {
                     $arrChartData[] = $row;
                 echo $row['title'] . " " . $row['startdate'];
                 echo "<br />";
                 }
         }//
         elseif($date=="pdate")
         {

             $arrChartData[] = array();
                $sql="select DISTINCT  * from 
             store where  startdate < CURRENT_DATE() AND title LIKE '%".$title."%' group by storeid ";


             $res = $con->query($sql) or trigger_error($con->error."[$sql]");
         while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
             {
                 $arrChartData[] = $row;
             echo $row['title'] . " " . $row['startdate'];
             echo "<br />";
             }
         }//

 }

 ?>
```

global.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#title').on('change', function () {
        var title = $('#title').val();
        if ($.trim(title) != '') {

            $.ajax({
            url: "title.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'title': title},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                 $('#title-data').html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqxhr) {
               $('#title-data').html(jqxhr.responseText); 
            }
         }); 
        }
    })//


    $('#datee').on('change', function () {

        var date = $('#datee').val();
        var title = $('#title').val();
        if ($.trim(date) != '') {
         $.ajax({
            url: "title.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'date': date, 'title': title},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                 $('#title-data').html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqxhr) {
               $('#title-data').html(jqxhr.responseText); 
            }
         }); 
        }
    })//
})
```

please suggest me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance for coder

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicated records in the database. The initial select query that builds the select would suggest that you have.

Comment: yes. I have no duplicate records in the database.

Comment: So the title Kohls and Macy's dsad must appear twice with a different store id. Try adding the store id to the output just to confirm. Otherwise you can use DISTINCT as you do when getting the date or use GROUP BY title

Comment: At first I tried with Group by title but failed then I it grouped with id. However you can see the dropdown data hear [link](http://speedymarket.byethost5.com/fd/index.php)

Comment: It looks correct to me. You now have one of each record a and b and this now reflect in the drop down list.